# PowerPivot problem with joining several tables with dates

Tags: ms-access, powerbi, dax, powerpivot

I'm trying to build some scoreboard based on Access source databases but I cannot understand the relations needed to join several tables containing dates. On this occasion I've prepared some samples.

[image]

Gray tables contain source data, blue one contains expected result.

I made the connections between the tables in the following way:

[image]

But there's still problem with using slicer, pivot table shows only partial data, I don't have more ideas how to make it working properly.

Comment: Why would hours spent be only 7.5 and not 15.5? Only want Admin hours? Are there really only 1 admin and 1 manager in company? Why does Users show Manager1 but Time Tracking just shows Manager? Date is a reserved word and really should not use reserved words as names for anything. Also advise not to use spaces nor punctuation/special characters in naming convention.

Comment: Name is also a reserved word.

Answer (score 0):

The following query obtains desired output with sample data. No pivot involved. Notice use of compound joins.

```
SELECT Audit.Date, Users.Name, Users_1.Name AS Manager, 
WorkReport.OrdersFinished, TimeTrackingSystem.Hours, 
[OrdersFinished]/[Hours] AS OrdersPerHour, Audit.AuditScorePct
FROM WorkReport 
INNER JOIN (TimeTrackingSystem 
INNER JOIN (Users AS Users_1 
INNER JOIN (Users 
INNER JOIN Audit ON Users.User = Audit.User) ON Users_1.User = Users.Manager) 
ON (TimeTrackingSystem.User = Audit.User) AND (TimeTrackingSystem.Date = Audit.Date))
ON (WorkReport.User = Audit.User) AND (WorkReport.Date = Audit.Date)
WHERE (((TimeTrackingSystem.Action)="Work") AND ((Audit.User)="Admin"));
```